# Custom control published property does not exist

Tags: c++, properties, c++builder-xe7

I have a custom control to which I am trying to add a property which can be set in the Object Inspector.  According to [this documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Published), I need to place the property under the `__published` section of my header file.

```
__published:
    __property  bool ShowErrorIcon = { read=FShowErrorIcon,write=FShowErrorIcon };
```

I set up the property to read and write to the private bool `FShowErrorIcon`

```
private:
    bool FShowErrorIcon;
```

However, when I launch the form that contains one of these controls I get the following error:

"Error reading RgnSearchBar.ShowErrorIcon: Property ShowErrorIcon does not exist."

This is confusing me, because the property is clearly visible in the ObjectInspector when the control is selected.  What step am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an older version of the component binaries on your HDD. The version of the component that is loaded in the IDE is newer then the version that is getting linked into your executable.  Somewhere, an older version is on the search path before the newer version, so the compiler/linker is linking the old version. You need to find and remove that older version.